# Can't deploy to JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run some integrationtests after changing app server from Glassfish to JBoss 7.1. However it can't be deployed. It is throwing this error aand then it stops.

> 20:35:31,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread -
>   9) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment
>   "9965db9f-a190-4bca-b7a9-c7df3ea6b1d7.war" was rolled back with
>   failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable
>   dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.9965db9f-a190-4bca-b7a9-c7df3ea6b1d7.war\".mainjboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.arquillian-service\".mainMissing[jboss.module.service.\"deployment.9965db9f-a190-4bca-b7a9-c7df3ea6b1d7.war\".mainjboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.arquillian-service\".main]"]}

This is my POM:

```
    <!-- Arquillian dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of Surefire are you using? Also, does this problem occur when you use the Servlet protocol, instead of the default used by AS7 - JMX?

Comment: Please also add your deployment code.